# ePSXe or pSX do not work

Tags: 11.10, games, emulation

ePSXe is my favor emulator. It does not work in Ubuntu 11.10.
It ask me for libgtk1.2 and I cant find it within 11.10?
pSX told me that:

```
(pSX:6367): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
[src/linux/sound.cpp, line 215]: 'snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle,hwparams,SND_PCM_ACCESS_MMAP_INTERLEAVED)' returned 'Invalid argument'
pad=0
```

I have no idea about that.
It there anyone can help?
Why removing libgtk1.2 ???

Answer (score 3):

pSX isn't broken for me.

**If you already installed `libgtkglext1` from package manager:**

The problem that shows you have around pulseaudio was included.

The easier solution is runing pSX like root (`sudo ./pSX`), the emulator shows and run. Then you should change the audio conf at file/configuration and sound tab.

The device is setting like "Default" and need to be your device name (change this option with your dev). Now you can close the emulator.

Look for the `psx.ini` file in the root folder (`/root/.pSX/psx.ini`) and copy the sound device code, this would look like this:

```
[Sound]
Frequency=-1
Sync=1
Reverb=1
Interpolate=1
Latency=32
XALatency=20
Device=b7d317a4 (this is my dev, your could be different)
```

Now open the INI file, but the one of your user (for example: `/home/yourusername/.pSX/psx.ini`) and paste the device code that you copy before.

Your emulator should run fine now.

Don't know if the epsxe problem share the same solution.

Comment: great answer. Also, x64 users still experiencing problems should install the required x86 (32 bits) libs, then it works fine in x64 ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

pSX seems to be broken; I've asked about it before and haven't been able to get an answer. As for ePSXe, my guess is that libgtk has been upgraded a couple of times and v1.2 is now deprecated. In any case, you may want to try PCSX-Reloaded, it's in the Ubuntu Software Center. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can run ePSXe in Ubuntu 14.04. So I think it should work in previous Ubuntu versions as well. It took me some days of trial and error until I found a decent solution. I have a 64 bit machine and can't assure this is going to work with a 32 bit operating system.

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libglib1.2ldbl_1.2.10-19build1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgtk1.2-common_1.2.10-18.1build2_all.deb
sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines:i386
```

I don't know if the next packages are necessary but there will be no harm on installing them:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt-get install unity-gtk2-module:i386
```

If you are going to use *spuEternal* sound plugin (it's my favorite) you should download `libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15-5ubuntu1_i386.deb` and extract its contents to copy the shared libraries. You need `libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4` and `libSDL-1.2.so.0` (which is a symlink). Copy those two a any place you want (I like to create a subdirectory inside of epsxe directory).

Now extract `libgtk1.2_1.2.10-18.1build2_i386.deb` contents and all lib directory contents to the lib directory (inside epsxe directory) you created on the previous step.

Now go the lib directory (the one you have just created) and do this:

```
ln -s libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4 libSDL.so
```

In order to configurate spuEternal plugin the previous step is necessary.

Now create a bash to run ePSXe:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset GTK_MODULES
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/yourusername/epsxe/lib /home/yourusername/epsxe/epsxe
```

I hope this can be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

To use pSX on Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Lubuntu/etc (up to 15.04 32/64bit**):

Download/Install

1. Download pSX tarbell from [here](http://psxemulator.gazaxian.com/pSX_linux_1_13.tar.bz2)
2. Unpack into your favorite location. /opt/pSX, or some other place where pSX will be on the PATH is good (don't forget to add `/opt/pSX` to your `/etc/environment` or your profile if you are a non-admin user -- mine's in `/usr/bin` since it is already in the `PATH` (also `$HOME/bin` is in the `PATH` on most systems).
3. Install *your version* of the required *32-bit* libraries, either by using `sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1:i386` or `dpkg --install libgtkglext1_<your version>.deb` where your version can come from here: [10.04-11.10](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtkglext/libgtkglext1_1.2.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) * [12.04-13.10](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtkglext/libgtkglext1_1.2.0-2fakesync1_i386.deb) * [14.04](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtkglext/libgtkglext1_1.2.0-3.1fakesync3_i386.deb) * [14.10/15.04](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gtkglext/libgtkglext1_1.2.0-3.2fakesync1_i386.deb) )

The other way around pulseaudio

4. You do not *need* to use sudo to run pSX (however that works too). Just make sure pulseaudio is not running at the time. Use `pactl exit`, or, if that does not work; `killall pulseaudio -SIGKILL`. If it restarts itself immediately, autorespawn is turned on, so you will need to turn it off. To do this, you need to edit your `/etc/pulse/client.conf` so that `autospawn=no` (dont forget to remove the `;` comment!). And no, `/usr/bin/pasuspender` (and consequently, `/usr/bin/pacmd suspend`) will NOT work in this case.
5. pSX seems to work best with the PsOne bios, since it is the most up-to-date bios code there is, and, probably what the programmers *did not* use during devlopment ;) . I would provide a link, but that's not really legal.
6. Steps **7**, **8**, and **9** are *optional* -- but will make first-time, and continued, use of pSX a bit easier. I purposefully put the last step AFTER them in hopes that you may read them anyways :)

Optional First-Time-Run Preparations

7. *(optional)* When you start the pSX binary for the first time, you may want to start it from the directory you wish to keep your pSX-related directories in. Usually `~/.pSX`, or else it may choose create (usually just cdimages) directories wherever you were where you started it. Also, you may want to `touch ~/.pSX/memcards/card{1,2}.mcd` before running so you have some empty cards to start off with. *Remember, this only applies to the FIRST time you start it as a given user AND have no existing psx.ini.*
8. *(optional)* If you want a .desktop icon on your desktop, you can use [this default one](https://gist.github.com/osirisgothra/813ac8effb70bea83e1a#file-gistfile1-txt).
9. *(optional)* The official icon for pSX, you may want, [can be downloaded here](http://easyweb.easynet.co.uk/~david.s/saturn/images/Playstation_icon.gif)

Execute!

10. Once pulseaudio is out of the picture you can just run it as a normal user. Please be aware that if you want GTK themes to work properly, you will need the 32-bit theme engines installed. This can be tricky with Ubuntu, however it is not required (just bell-and-whistle thing).

...or not!

11. If you are still at a no-go, you can [download this set of i386 libraries](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B395V-m6_bERSDVsdW9tNEhyQTA/view?usp=sharing), and point your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to them. The libraries provided may or may not work with your card (best chance if NVidia GT chipset, you could just overwrite with the good libraries you have, see the MANIFEST) this is USUALLY not required. After that, return to step 4 and try again.

...then go play some games!

As for ePSXe, i dont use that one because i didn't like it but i think the answers above mine are good from what I can see.

** tested and used pSX with Ubuntu/Kubuntu versions 10.04 all the way up to current 15.04 without problems, both in 32-bit AND (more often than not) 64-bit environments.

- pSX with ATI Radeon cards seem to suck on linux...bad, unless you have something newer and well supported, I recommend the NVidia GeForce GT 610 at the least, which is pretty decent (can get up to 70FPS easily).